# Disable Spring Security Basic Login - Spring REST web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my SecurityConfig.java,

```
    @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
            .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().anonymous().and().httpBasic();
}
```

How do I totally disable Spring Security, in a way that I am able to access my web service without having to input "user" and "password"?

Comment: Try using `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` instead of what you have and let me know

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer for future readers to easily find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Spring Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Make note that this does not disable in Spring Security from the request chain, it just tells Spring Security to allow all requests